# In general - How do I sum polynomial sequences like $3.7 + 5.9+...$ in closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm perusing an old book (*Operators* by D.R. Dickinson) which has a section showing how to sum for example

$$3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 + 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 9 + \cdots + (2n+1)(2n+3)(2n+5)$$

For the generic, closed-form solution the book gives, it matters that the difference between successive factors in a given term is the same as the difference between the corresponding factors in successive terms.

Here we have $3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$ with *factor* difference of $2$, and also the first term (**3**.5.7) starts with $3$, the second term (**5**.7.9) starts with 5.

For the record, what they do to sum the above is to firstly write

$$u_{r} = \prod_{s = 0}^{m-1} [a + (r+s-1)b]$$

This way, you can change either r or s and compensate (by adjusting limit m) to get the same thing.
Now they have an auxillary definition, applying when $r \geq 1$

$v_{r}=\prod_{s = 0}^{m} [a + (r+s-1)b] \quad \quad$
This time, notice index $s$ stops at $m$ rather than (m-1).

for $r \ge 1$

$$v_{r} = u_{r}.[a + (r+m-1)b]$$

also

$$v_{r_{-1}} = \prod_{s = 0}^{m} [a + (r+s-2)b] = [a + (r+s-2)b].u_{r}$$

Therefore

$$v_{r} - u_{r-1} = (m+1).b.u_{r}$$

$$\sum_{r = 1}^{n} u_{r} = \dfrac{1}{(m+1).b}(v_n-v_0)$$

I hope I've written that correctly - I have slightly changed the book's rather opaque presentation.

Okay - But now how about this
$3.7 + 5.9+...+(2n+1)(2n+5)$

The way they tackle this is to first derive some "standard forms" (which I have labeled F1, F2, F3)

$\sum_{r = 1}^{n} 1 = n \quad \quad (F_1)$

$\sum_{r = 1}^{n} r = \dfrac{1}{2}n(n+1) \quad \quad (F_2)$

$\sum_{r = 1}^{n} r(r+1) = \dfrac{1}{3}n(n+1)(n+2) \quad \quad (F_3)$

Now, expand the new problem, i.e.
$u_r = (2r+1)(2r+5) = 4r^2+12r+5 = 4r(r+1) + 8r + 5$

Notice the term $r(r+1)$ is like the LHS of form F3, $8r$ is like F2 and $5$ is like F1.

Therefore

$\sum_{r = 1}^{n} u_r = \dfrac{4}{3}n(n+1) + 4n(n+1) + 5n$

Now the above is some work and is not a closed form in a generic sense for series of similar form having say $6$ factors per term.

So - my question is

Is there a more generic way to approach this, not requiring those "Standard Forms" and not asking us to multiply out all factors in $u_r$?

Comment: The sledgehammer solution is to remember just that if $g(k)=\sum_{n=1}^k f(n)$ where $f(n)$ is a _polynomial_, then $g(n)$ is always a polynomial of degree one larger than $f$. In your case the general term is a degree-3 polynomial, so you're looking for a polynomial of degree 4. Compute five different values of $g(n)$ explicitly (starting with $g(0)=0$), and then solve for the unknown coefficients.

Comment: The title does not match the body.

Answer (score 2):

The general term can be written as

$$T_n=(2r+1)(2r+3)(2r+5)$$

$$8T_n=(2r+1)(2r+3)(2r+5)(2r+7)-(2r-1)(2r+1)(2r+3)(2r+5)$$

$$8T_n=V_{n+1}-V_n$$

Where $$V_n=(2r-1)(2r+1)(2r+3)(2r+5)$$

Now $$S=\sum_{r=1}^n T_r=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{r=1}^n(V_{r+1}-V_{r})$$

Now telescope to get $\displaystyle S=\boxed{\frac{V_{n+1}-V_1}{8}}$

Comment: Thanks - As I understand it, this is essentially a concrete example of the general method outlined above for the "well behaved" series? That is, with the above formula we have a=3, b=2, m=3 and (m+1).b = 8.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the given series as \begin{align} S_n = \sum_{r =1}^{n}((2r+1)(2r + 3)(2r + 5)) \\= \sum_{r =1}^{n} 8 \, r^{3} + 36 \, r^{2} + 46 \, r + 15 \\= 8 \sum_{r =1}^{n} r^3 + 36 \sum_{r =1}^{n}r^2 + 46 \sum_{r =1}^{n} r + \sum_{r =1}^{n}15 \end{align}

Using $$ \sum_{r =1}^{n}r^3 = \frac{1}{4} \, {\left(n + 1\right)}^{2} n^{2}$$ and $$\sum_{r =1}^{n} r^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$ and $$\sum_{r =1}^{n}r = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ we find that

> $$ S_n = 2 \, n^{4} + 16 \, n^{3} + 43 \, n^{2} + 44 \, n = {\left(2 \, n^{2} + 8 \, n + 11\right)} {\left(n + 4\right)} n$$

Comment: This seems to be applying the method outlined in the 2nd part of the question to the first part? Really, what I am seeking is a solution for sequences like the 2nd part, but having an arbitrary count of factors per term. The method using 'known forms' will clearly soon get unworkable when the count of factors grows large.

Answer (score 0):

As the general term is a polynomial, you can expand it and use the Faulhaber formulas for the respective terms. As Faulhaber is itself a closed-form, you will get a closed-form in all cases.

In the given example,

$$8n^3+36n^2+46n+15\to 2n^2(n+1)^2+6n(n+1)(2n+1)+23n(n+1)+15n\\=2n^4+16n^3+43n^2+44n.$$

---

You can also obtain that polynomial by Lagrangian interpolation on the first n+1 terms of the series.

Newtonian interpolation is even better for general terms that are products of $k$ integers in arithmetic progression.

In your case:

$$\Delta_1=(2n+3)(2n+5)(2n+7)$$
$$\Delta_2=6(2n+5)(2n+7)$$
$$\Delta_3=27(2n+7)$$
$$\Delta_3=54$$

Comment: That looks promising. My concern has been that soon as I have to expand those k terms then the solution is non-closed WRT k. Please can you provide some details on the 6, 27, 54, where they stem from and how to use them? For k factors, will I still have to do some work which grows with k? Is there a way to deal with arbitrary k (i.e terms having k factors)?

Comment: @SJB: the Faulhaber have an expression in $k$ that involves the Bernouilli numbers. That is not closed-form. I would be surprised that your case leads to a closed-form.